# Updating a column based on values from other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
Id  CategoryId  Code  Status
=================================
1   A100        0012  NULL
2   A100        0012  NULL
3   A100        0055  NULL
4   A100        0012  NULL
5   B201        1116  NULL
6   B201        1116  NULL
7   B201        1121  NULL
8   B201        1024  NULL
```

Logic: 1. For same CategoryID, code should be the same.
       2. If multiple code exists, consider the one with lowest value.

Desired result:

```
Id  CategoryId  Code  Status
=================================
1   A100        0012  NULL
2   A100        0012  NULL
3   A100        0055  FAIL
4   A100        0012  NULL
5   B201        1116  FAIL
6   B201        1116  FAIL
7   B201        1121  FAIL
8   B201        1024  NULL
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean; it's not allowing you to write code?

Comment: @Ben_53: "fail if code is different for same categoryid,else NULL" - how do you know which one is the "right" categoryid?

Comment: @Abe I believe the desired output is to set the `Status` column accordingly

Comment: business logic says that "All category ID  must have the same codes" Foe example in data, id = 3 have different code for same categoryid.

Comment: @Ben Say you have you two rows, `id=10, categoryID=ABCD, Code=xy11` and `id=11, categoryID=ABCD, Code=ab52`. Which one of them is the "right" one?

Comment: @Ben_53: Which one is the right code, so that others can be "different" from the "same"? Is the one with the lowest ID per categoryID the winner? Are they defined in a different table?, ...?

Comment: lets assume the first code is correct for corresponding different categoryID. so in this case, code with ID =1 and code with ID=5 is "right". thanks

Comment: @Ben - I have assumed on the basis of your example data and desired results that this is a gaps and islands problem and you are ordering the table by `id` looking at contiguous islands of `CategoryId` and if any within an island have a status different than the first one then that is a fail. Does that sound correct?

Comment: UPDATE : New added logic: If there exists multiple code for same categoryID, consider the lowest one. (code is int value) Thanks

Comment: @Ben Doesn't your edit invalidate your desired results? (and if not why not) For `B201` the `MIN(Code`) is 1024 so why isn't that the non Fail row?

Comment: @martin: sorry its all messed up. I edited the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your edit...

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
ID INT,
CategoryID CHAR(4),
Code CHAR(4),
Status CHAR(4) NULL
)
INSERT INTO @T (ID,CategoryID, Code)
SELECT 1,'A100',0012 UNION ALL SELECT 2,'A100',0012 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'A100',0055 UNION ALL SELECT 4,'A100',0012 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'B201',1116 UNION ALL SELECT 6,'B201',1116 UNION ALL
SELECT 7,'B201',1121 UNION ALL SELECT 8,'B201',1024;

WITH T AS
(
SELECT *, MIN(Code) OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryID ) AS MinCode
from @T
)
UPDATE T
SET Status = 'FAIL'
WHERE Code <> MinCode

SELECT *
FROM @T
```

Returns

```
ID          CategoryID Code Status
----------- ---------- ---- ------
1           A100       12   NULL
2           A100       12   NULL
3           A100       55   FAIL
4           A100       12   NULL
5           B201       1116 FAIL
6           B201       1116 FAIL
7           B201       1121 FAIL
8           B201       1024 NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab, though I really think it should be a new question.

```
;WITH o AS 
(
    SELECT Id, CategoryId, Code, Status, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CategoryId ORDER BY Id)
    FROM dbo.my_table
),
n AS 
(
    SELECT CategoryId, Code
    FROM o WHERE rn = 1
)
UPDATE o 
    SET [Status] = 'FAILURE'
    FROM o INNER JOIN n
    ON o.CategoryId = n.CategoryId 
    AND o.Code <> n.Code
    WHERE o.rn > 1;
```